# Compensated vs uncompensated Op Amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-electronics

What are the advantages/disadvantages of compensated and uncompensated op amps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Examine the datasheet for the UA709 operational amplifier. There are numerous compensation options, and the ability to adjust the poles is key to achieving precision gain at high frequencies. For example, gain of 60dB closed loop, out to 200KHz. Design and Datasheet are by Bob Widlar.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206299/op-amp-what-is-internal-frequency-compensation

Answer (score 2):

If you have to ask, then you shouldn't use an uncompensated one.

Uncompensated will give you a higher slew rate and more bandwidth than the equivalent compensated op-amp, but you'll have to know what you're doing to make it stable, you can't just fling it like you do with a compensated one.