# purpose of feedback capacitor in operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

Can someone explain what is the reason of using feedback capacitor in an amplifier? does it even matter if we don't use it?

Comment: Please be more clear in your question.  There are many ways that a capacitor might be used in feedback.  A schematic would probably help.

Comment: Integrator, high frequency filter.

Comment: Edit to show what configuration or circuit you mean... One of the NPN BJT inside a [compensated](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206299/op-amp-what-is-internal-frequency-compensation/206315#206315) op-amp circuit has capacitive feedback to stabilize the closed-loop feedback by attenuating the open-loop gain at high frequency, where there is more than 180 degrees of phase shift. (Most IC op-amps are compensated; uncompensated variants are sometimes available.) Or maybe you're asking about feedback outside the op-amp, as part of an integrator or active filter circuit?